# How can I make page for 403 and 404 errors in Django?

Tags: django

In other website like github I saw when the path is not found it returns error template for example look at github.com/ddfushdvbjkvuirfjvscvuiihkbfdsuhkb this page does not exist. Also I want to make for deleted path's that returns 403 error. Please send me some docs I didnt find out :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize your error views like this

```
handler404 = 'mysite.views.your_custom_view'

#render your custom template here
def your_custom_view(request):
    return render(request,'your_template')
```

See the official [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views) for more info

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to include `error_code.html` template in your root template directory
[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/views/#the-403-http-forbidden-view)
ex: `403.html`, `404.html` 
`your_app/template/404.html`